# What is the relationship between outer and [[scopes]]?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, google-chrome-devtools, v8

When a function is executed, an execution context is created, and the outer property in the lexical environment of the execution context points to the lexical environment of the upper-level execution context to obtain variables used during execution. Is the array maintained by [[Scopes]] all the lexical environments on the outer link? How are the two related? Is the determination of the scope chain related to the execution context, or is the execution context directly associated with the scope chain when it is created?

I'm trying to understand the relationship between "outer" and "[[scopes]]".

Comment: Scope is lexical, I think execution context is dynamic.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing these terms? A screenshot might help. It sounds like this is more related to the devtools UI than to the V8 engine.

Answer (score -1):

The **"outer"** property in a lexical environment refers to the lexical environment of the parent execution context. It is used to resolve variables and functions that are not defined within the current lexical environment.

The **[[Scopes]]** internal property of a function object is a list of all the lexical environments that are in the scope chain of the function. It is used to create the scope chain for each new execution context that is created when the function is called. The list includes not only the outer lexical environment, but also any lexical environments that are nested within the outer lexical environment.

In summary, the **"outer"** property in a lexical environment refers to the lexical environment of the parent execution context, while the **[[Scopes]]** internal property of a function object is a list of all the lexical environments that are in the scope chain of the function.

Comment: "*lexical environment of the parent execution context.*" - no. Which execution context are you even referring to?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).